# Pivoting in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

I have to transpose my rows into columns from a DB2 table.This is how my table is structured..

```
ItemID    Item    Value
---------------------
1     Meeting     Now
1     Advise      Yes
1     NoAdvise    No
2     Meeting     Never
2     Advise      No
2     NoAdvise    Null
2     Combine    Yes
```

I want this to be transposed into(note that I do not want to transpose Combine)

```
ItemID    Meeting  Advise   NoAdvise 
---------------------------------------
1         Now      Yes       No
2         Never    No        Null
```

Bit struggling with the query, can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but it should work.  DB2 doesn't have a built-in [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, like SQL Server.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
     A.ItemID
    ,(SELECT value
      FROM table B
      WHERE B.ItemID = A.ItemID
        AND B.Item   = 'Meeting'
    ) AS Meeting
    ,(SELECT value
      FROM table B
      WHERE B.ItemID = A.ItemID
        AND B.Item   = 'Advise'
    ) AS Advise
    ,(SELECT value
      FROM table B
      WHERE B.ItemID = A.ItemID
        AND B.Item   = 'NoAdvise'
    ) AS NoAdvise
FROM table A
```

Answer (score 6):

The [currently accepted answer by bhamby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15531637/521799) is certainly correct, but it's worth checking [if using several correlated subqueries is much slower than a single group by](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/) (hint: it most likely is):

```sql
SELECT 
  A.ItemID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN A.Item = 'Meeting'  THEN Value END) AS Meeting,
  MAX(CASE WHEN A.Item = 'Advise'   THEN Value END) AS Advise,
  MAX(CASE WHEN A.Item = 'NoAdvise' THEN Value END) AS NoAdvise
FROM A
GROUP BY A.ItemID
```

It's also a bit simpler in my opinion

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/1358) (in PostgreSQL, but works on DB2 LUW as well)

Answer (score 0):

As @bhamby said, DB2 doesn't have a `PIVOT` function.
Mostly, my query just differs in how the results are retrieved - you'd need to run the profiler/optimizer over them to be sure, but I believe that the correlated sub-queries may be executed per-row (potentially less efficient), rather than as sets.  This is unlikely to be an issue over small datasets.

```
WITH Item (id) as (SELECT DISTINCT itemId
                   FROM YourTable),
SELECT item.id, Meeting.meeting, Advise.advise, NoAdvise.noadvise
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemId, value as meeting
           FROM YourTable
           WHERE item = 'Meeting') as Meeting
       ON Meeting.itemId = Item.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemId, value as advise
           FROM YourTable
           WHERE item = 'Advise') as Advise
       ON Advise.itemId = Item.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemId, value as noadvise
           FROM YourTable
           WHERE item = 'NoAdvise') as NoAdvise
       ON NoAdvise.itemId = Item.id
```

(... Actually, I'm a little concerned that you have columns for both 'advise' and 'no advise', which would appear to be some sort of boolean condition - ie, you should have one, but not the other).