# Pivoting DB2 Data - where number of columns and and rows are not fixed

Tags: sql, db2

I've seen a few similar Q/A's on here, but the cases I've seen were variations on the "sales by year across quarter" variety, so DECODE is used, with 4 categories.

In my case, I don't know in advance how many rows or columns the pivot will have.

```
| Pay | Age | Value |

|-----|-----|-------|

| 1   | 1   | 10    |

| 1   | 2   | 20    |

| 1   | 3   | 30    |

| 2   | 1   | 90    |

| 2   | 2   | 80    |

| 2   | 3   | 70    |
```

and we want the result set as

```
PAYGROUP      Millennials     GenX     Boomers   
1                10            20       30              
2                90            80       70
```

This would be easy with a `PIVOT` statement, i.e.

```
Transform Max(VALUE) AS V
SELECT PAYGROUP
FROM table
GROUP BY PAYGROUP
PIVOT AGEGROUP;
```

but my **DB2** has no `PIVOT` function.

The number of pay groups and age groups may vary from case to case, e.g., the data can have different numbers of pay and age groupings for different cases.

Comment: If it isn't fixed, then you should consider doing this in your application code

Comment: No RDBMS allows runtime columns in a `PIVOT` statement, since the column definitions can't be data fields.  This _must_ to be done with dynamic sql.  After you get the list of 'column' values, the [standard techniques apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but only within an SQL procedure or other HLL.

You used one SQL statement to find out what/how many distinct values then build a dynamic SQL statement using those values.

Can probably point you to an example if you add your DB2 platform and version to the question.

Here's a pure SQL procedure (originally for DB2 for IBM i but should work for LUW ) found here: https://www.itjungle.com/2015/04/21/fhg042115-story01/

```
SET SCHEMA = WHER_YOU_WANT_IT;

CREATE PROCEDURE DO_PIVOT
   (IN FOR_SCHEMA CHARACTER (10) , 
    IN FOR_TABLE CHARACTER (10) , 
    IN PIVOT_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
    IN VALUE_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
    IN AGG_FUNCTION VARCHAR (5) DEFAULT 'SUM' , 
    IN GROUP_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    PROGRAM TYPE SUB 
    CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL COMMIT ON RETURN NO 

BEGIN

   DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
   DECLARE SQL_STATEMENT VARCHAR ( 5000 ) ;
   DECLARE PIVOT_VALUE VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
   DECLARE PAD CHAR ( 2 ) DEFAULT ' ' ;

   DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR D1 ;
   DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR D2 ;

   SET SCHEMA = FOR_SCHEMA ;

   -- Get the list of values available for the pivot column
   -- Each value will be a column in the return set
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select distinct ' 
                       || PIVOT_COLUMN  
                       || ' from ' 
                       || FOR_TABLE 
                       || ' order by 1' ;

   PREPARE D1 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
   OPEN C1 ;

   -- Construct a dynamic select statement for the pivot
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select ' ;

   -- If requested, add the Group By Column 
   -- to the select clause
   IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT || GROUP_COLUMN ;
      SET PAD = ', ' ;
   END IF ;

   -- For each possible value for the Pivot Column, 
   -- add a case statement to perform the requested 
   -- aggregate function on the Value Column
   FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
   WHILE ( SQLCODE >= 0 AND SQLCODE <> 100 ) DO
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                          || PAD 
                          || AGG_FUNCTION 
                          || '(CASE WHEN ' 
                          || PIVOT_COLUMN 
                          || ' = ''' 
                          || PIVOT_VALUE 
                          || ''' THEN ' 
                          || VALUE_COLUMN 
                          || '  END) AS ' 
                          || PIVOT_VALUE ;
      SET PAD = ', ' ;
      FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
   END WHILE ;
   CLOSE C1 ;

   -- Specify the table to select from
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                       || ' from ' 
                       || FOR_TABLE ;

   -- If requested, add the Group By Column
   -- to the select clause
   IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                          || ' group by ' 
                          || GROUP_COLUMN 
                          || ' order by ' 
                          || GROUP_COLUMN;
   END IF ;

   PREPARE D2 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
   OPEN C2 ;

END ;

LABEL ON ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
   ( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() )  
   IS 'Perform a General Purpose Pivot';

COMMENT ON PARAMETER ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
   ( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() ) 
   (FOR_SCHEMA IS 'Schema for Table' , 
    FOR_TABLE IS 'For Table' , 
    PIVOT_COLUMN IS 'Name of Column to be Pivoted' , 
    VALUE_COLUMN IS 'Column to be Aggregated for Pivot' , 
    AGG_FUNCTION IS 'Use Aggregate Function' , 
    GROUP_COLUMN IS 'Group on Column' ) ;
```

I think you could also use the XML functions to pivot the data...but I've yet to find a good example of that

Comment: It's DB2/v9 FWIW.  I am still curious about a clever SQL approach, but am going to pivot the recordset "the hard way" in the client(JSP)  application.  Still an SQL-only solution would be nice.