# Pivot DB2 SQL SubQuery

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, pivot

This query gives me the results number of people with age and country. Below is a picture that I needed. Just like a Pivot table.

[image]

```
    SELECT count(age) AS numberofpeople, age, country
    FROM (

    SELECT person_id,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(256,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(a.admission_date) - TIMESTAMP(p.dateofbirth))) AS Age, 
    dateofbirth,
    a.admission_date

    FROM person p
    LEFT JOIN admission a ON p.person_id = a.person_id

  WHERE category = '1' 
    AND startdate BETWEEN '8/1/2016' AND '10/31/2017') AS a 
    WHERE age <= '10'
    GROUP BY country, age
```

Thank you

Comment: more of a scatter chart look to it.

Comment: Check out the other pivot questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher I follow the given solution and getting this error: The operand of the column function "MAX" includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery.