# Pivoting a table in iSeries DB2 dynamically

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

So what I'm trying to do is convert rows into columns. This has been covered before on this site in a verity of ways, the way I like the best is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  FRNPCM032.WFP.WFORD#,
  MAX(CASE WHEN FRNPCM032.WFP.WFSEGN = 'COLOR1'  THEN WFVAL END) AS COLOR,
  MAX(CASE WHEN FRNPCM032.WFP.WFSEGN = 'OSKVA'  THEN WFVAL END) AS KVA,
  MAX(CASE WHEN FRNPCM032.WFP.WFSEGN = 'OSSWITCH'  THEN WFVAL END) AS LBSWITCH
FROM FRNPCM032.WFP
GROUP BY FRNPCM032.WFP.WFORD#;
```

This is a very simple way, but I need something less manual than this because new rows might be added later and I dont want to have to go back to keep maintaining a query or view.

Is there a way I can dynamically do this? I can think of a way to do it with loops, but i cant do that in a query or view.

Comment: It doesn't seem like IBM D2 has a `PIVOT` method like other RDBMS's as seen in [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2). Consider using general-purpose code (Java, Python, C#, PHP, VB, Perl, R) to reshape resultset. All such can connect to DB2. SQL is a special-purpose, declarative language really designed for immutable, set-based retrieval and manipulation not dynamic reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DB2 for IBM i doesn't have a PIVOT() function...

However, you can build a procedure that dynamically looks at the current contents of the table and builds an SQL statement that pivots the data.

The following code was taken from the article, [An SQL Pivot Procedure](https://www.itjungle.com/2015/04/21/fhg042115-story01/)

If you wanted you could modify the code to build a view, rather than returning a result set.  But you'd have to rebuild the view if the pivot values changed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DO_PIVOT
   (IN FOR_SCHEMA CHARACTER (10) , 
    IN FOR_TABLE CHARACTER (10) , 
    IN PIVOT_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
    IN VALUE_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) , 
    IN AGG_FUNCTION VARCHAR (5) DEFAULT 'SUM' , 
    IN GROUP_COLUMN VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    PROGRAM TYPE SUB 
    CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL COMMIT ON RETURN NO 

BEGIN

   DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
   DECLARE SQL_STATEMENT VARCHAR ( 5000 ) ;
   DECLARE PIVOT_VALUE VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
   DECLARE PAD CHAR ( 2 ) DEFAULT ' ' ;

   DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR D1 ;
   DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR D2 ;

   SET SCHEMA = FOR_SCHEMA ;

   -- Get the list of values available for the pivot column
   -- Each value will be a column in the return set
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select distinct ' 
                       || PIVOT_COLUMN  
                       || ' from ' 
                       || FOR_TABLE 
                       || ' order by 1' ;

   PREPARE D1 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
   OPEN C1 ;

   -- Construct a dynamic select statement for the pivot
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = 'select ' ;

   -- If requested, add the Group By Column 
   -- to the select clause
   IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT || GROUP_COLUMN ;
      SET PAD = ', ' ;
   END IF ;

   -- For each possible value for the Pivot Column, 
   -- add a case statement to perform the requested 
   -- aggregate function on the Value Column
   FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
   WHILE ( SQLCODE >= 0 AND SQLCODE <> 100 ) DO
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                          || PAD 
                          || AGG_FUNCTION 
                          || '(CASE WHEN ' 
                          || PIVOT_COLUMN 
                          || ' = ''' 
                          || PIVOT_VALUE 
                          || ''' THEN ' 
                          || VALUE_COLUMN 
                          || '  END) AS ' 
                          || PIVOT_VALUE ;
      SET PAD = ', ' ;
      FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO PIVOT_VALUE ;
   END WHILE ;
   CLOSE C1 ;

   -- Specify the table to select from
   SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                       || ' from ' 
                       || FOR_TABLE ;

   -- If requested, add the Group By Column
   -- to the select clause
   IF GROUP_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET SQL_STATEMENT = SQL_STATEMENT 
                          || ' group by ' 
                          || GROUP_COLUMN 
                          || ' order by ' 
                          || GROUP_COLUMN;
   END IF ;

   PREPARE D2 FROM SQL_STATEMENT ;
   OPEN C2 ;

END ;

LABEL ON ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
   ( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() )  
   IS 'Perform a General Purpose Pivot';

COMMENT ON PARAMETER ROUTINE DO_PIVOT 
   ( CHAR(), CHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR(), VARCHAR() ) 
   (FOR_SCHEMA IS 'Schema for Table' , 
    FOR_TABLE IS 'For Table' , 
    PIVOT_COLUMN IS 'Name of Column to be Pivoted' , 
    VALUE_COLUMN IS 'Column to be Aggregated for Pivot' , 
    AGG_FUNCTION IS 'Use Aggregate Function' , 
    GROUP_COLUMN IS 'Group on Column' ) ;
```

Comment: As near as I'm aware, nobody's implementation of `PIVOT` allows dynamic columns, so you'd have to do this anywhere.