# Trouble pivoting data in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Before this one is marked as duplicate please know I have done my research on Pivoting in DB2 (even though DB2 doesnt have `PIVOT`) from these links
[Pivoting in DB2 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2) and [IBM Developers](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en), but I just cant make sense of how to do it with my Data and need some help.  I tried to manipulate my string using examples from both of those links and could not get it to work.  Im not asking for anyone to write the full code for me, but just give me a point in the right direction on how to change my string to retrieve the desired result.  Thank you in advance.

Current String:

```
SELECT 
  cfna1 AS "Customer Name", cfrisk AS "Risk Rating", cfrirc AS "Rated By", date(digits(decimal(cfrid7 + 0.090000, 7, 0))) AS "Risk Rated Date",cfuc3n3 AS "Credit Score", date(digits(decimal(cf3ud7 + 0.090000, 7, 0))) AS "CR Date"
  FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast
  WHERE cfcif# IN ('T000714', 'T000713', 'T000716', 'T000715')
ORDER BY
  CASE cfcif# 
    WHEN 'T000714' THEN 1
    WHEN 'T000713' THEN 2
    WHEN 'T000716' THEN 3 
    WHEN 'T000715' THEN 4
  END
```

Result as expected from String:

```
Customer Name | Risk Rating | Rated By | Risk Rated Date | Credit Score | CR Date
Elmer Fudd         8            MLA        2018-02-08        777           2018-02-08
```

Result I would like to achieve:

```
               Elmer Fudd
Risk Rating        8
Rated By          MLA
Risk Rated Date  2018-02-08
Credit Score      777
CR Date          2018-02-08
```

Comment: this makes no sense... that is not what the output of a select statement looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use unpivot method suggested in developers link and use cast to convert all columns to varchar.

Example:

```
select st1.id1, unpivot1.col1, unpivot1.val1
  from (
      select id1, char1 , date1, number1
      from sometable
    ) st1, 
    lateral (values 
      ('char col', cast(st1.char1 as varchar(100))), 
      ('date col', cast(st1.date1 as varchar(100))),
      ('number col', cast(st1.number1 as varchar(100))) 
    ) as unpivot1 (col1, val1)
  order by st1.id1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was not able to get this to work due to my lack of skill with SQL.  I ended up just manipulating the data in Excel since Excel is where the final product ends up.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that output is possible in sql -- do you mean something like this?

```
id_group  Data_Type       Value
1         Name            Elmer Fudd
1         Risk Rating     8
1         Rated By        MLA
1         Risk Rated Date 2018-02-08
1         Credit Score    777
1         CR Date         2018-02-08
```

To do this we need another column that brings all the elements together -- I called it "id_group" this is the column that identifys the group

Comment: Yes this is the result im looking for, sorry im relatively new to SQL.

Comment: ok just so you know.  I am not allowed to create any tables in the Database even temporary ones :(