# grouping db2 results of multiple rows to give columns for the different results

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a fairly simple query that executes correctly in DB2 but I'm having troubles figuring out how to group results to give me 2 columns with 
values that replace the colum of 2 different rows. In other words, for each product I get 2 rows (one with active price, one with temporary price)
but I want to make it so that I get one distinct product row with a column for each price type and the price

The query:

```
    select distinct grouping, body, fabric,color,thread,detail, category,p.priceType,p.price
    from ordering offs
    inner join pricing p
    on offs.body = p.bodyp
    where priceType in ('Active','Temporary')
    and offs.category in ('A','B','C');
```

What I'm getting:

```
    grouping  |  body  |  fabric  |  color  |  thread  |  detail  |  category  |  p.priceType  |  price
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ABC          123        1234       Blue     1.1       1           TEXTILE       Active          594.00
    ABC          123        1234       Blue     1.1       1           TEXTILE       Temporary       560.00
    ABC          123        1234       Red      0.5       0           TEXTILE       Active          584.00
    ABC          123        1234       Red      0.5       0           TEXTILE       Temporary       550.00
    ABC          123        1234       Grn      3.3       12          TEXTILE       Active          594.00
    ABC          123        1234       Grn      3.3       12          TEXTILE       Temporary       560.00
```

What I want to get:

```
    grouping  |  body  |  fabric  |  color  |  thread  |  detail  |  category  |  ActivePrice  |  TemporaryPrice
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ABC          123        1234       Blue     1.1       1           TEXTILE       594.00            560.00
    ABC          123        1234       Red      0.5       0           TEXTILE       584.00            550.00
    ABC          123        1234       Grn      3.3       12          TEXTILE       594.00            560.00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select grouping, body, fabric, color, thread, detail, category, 
      max(case when p.priceType = 'Active' then p.price end) as active_price,
      max(case when p.priceType = 'Temporary' then p.price end) as temporary_price
from ordering offs inner join
     pricing p
     on offs.body = p.bodyp
where priceType in ('Active', 'Temporary') and
      offs.category in ('A', 'B', 'C')
group by grouping, body, fabric, color, thread, detail, category;
```

Comment: This seems to still be giving me separate rows, only one will have active and temp will be null and vice versa

Comment: I think it's because I'm grouping by price which creates a distinctino between the two rows

Comment: @TomN. . . . I removed those columns from the `SELECT`, but not the `GROUP BY`.  It is now fixed.