# DB2: How to transpose mutlidimensional table from row to column to find data changes across rows

Tags: db2

I am trying the following with Db2:

**Problem**

So I've got a table with 80+ columns and two rows.

I need to accomplish is checking what columns have changed value between the two rows, and return a table of the column names that have changed, their initial value from row1, and their new value from row2.

**Approach so far**

My initial idea was to `perform a pivot of the two rows into two columns`, row 1 as column 1, row 2 as column 2, then join a column of column names (likely taken from syscat.columns) to the table as column 3, at which point I can then do a select where column1 != column2, hence returning the rows with all the data needed. But alas, it was not long after coming up with this that `I discover DB2 doesn't support pivot / unpivot...`

**Question**

So is there any idea for how to accomplish this in DB2, taking a table with 80+ columns and two rows like so:

```
| Col A | Col B | Col C | ... | Col Z|
| ----- | ----- | ----- | --- | ---- |
| Val A | Val B | 123 | ... | 01/01/2021 |
| Val C | Val B | 124 | ... | 02/01/2021 |
```

And returning a table with the columns changed, their initial value, and their new value:

```
| Initial | New | ColName|
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
| Val A | Val C | Col A |
| 123 | 124 | Col C |
| 01/01/2021 | 02/01/2021 | Col Z |
```

Also note the column data types also vary, so will need to be converted to varchar

DB2 version is 11.1

EDIT: Also for reference as per comment request, this is code I attempted to use to achieve this goal:

```
WITH
    INIT AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOMEDATE=(SELECT MIN(SOMEDATE) FROM TABLE),
    LATE AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOMEDATE=(SELECT MAX(SOMEDATE) FROM TABLE),
    COLS AS (SELECT COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABNAME='TABLE' ORDER BY COLNO)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        COLNAME AS ATTRIBUTE,
        (SELECT COLNAME AS INITIAL FROM INIT),
        (SELECT COLNAME AS NEW FROM LATE)
    FROM
        COLS
    WHERE
        (INITIAL != NEW) OR (INITIAL IS NULL AND NEW IS NOT NULL) OR (INITIAL IS NOT NULL AND NEW IS NULL));
```

Only issue with this one is that I couldn't figure how to use the values from the COLS table as the columns to be selected

Comment: What version and platform of Db2? Share the SQL statement you have tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivoting in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)

Comment: The solutions in that link do provide a method for a pivot like behavior in DB2, but they're not really feasible when it comes to a large number of columns, it would result in 80+ Select As statements in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You may easily generate text of the expressions needed, if you don't want to type them manually.
Consider the following example, if you want to print different column values only in 2 rows of the same quite a wide table `SYSCAT.TABLES`. We use the following query for such an expression generation.

```
SELECT 
  'DECODE(I.I, ' 
|| LISTAGG(COLNO || ', A.' || COLNAME || CASE WHEN TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%CHAR%' AND TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%GRAPHIC' THEN '::VARCHAR(128)' ELSE '' END, ', ') 
|| ') AS INITIAL' AS EXPR_INITIAL
, 'DECODE(I.I, ' 
|| LISTAGG(COLNO || ', B.' || COLNAME || CASE WHEN TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%CHAR%' AND TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%GRAPHIC' THEN '::VARCHAR(128)' ELSE '' END, ', ')
|| ') AS NEW' AS EXPR_NEW
, 'DECODE(I.I, ' 
|| LISTAGG(COLNO || ', ''' || COLNAME || '''', ', ')
|| ') AS COLNAME' AS EXPR_COLNAME
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'SYSCAT' AND TABNAME = 'TABLES'
    AND TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%LOB';
```

It doesn't matter how many columns the table contains. We just filter out the columns of *LOB types as an example. If you want them as well, you should change the `::VARCHAR(128)` casting to some `::CLOB(XXX)`.
These 3 generated expressions we put to the corresponding places in the query below:

```
WITH MYTAB AS
(
-- We enumerate the rows to reference them later
SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER () RN_, T.*
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'SYSCAT'
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
--   Place here the result got in the EXPR_INITIAL column
-- , Place here the result got in the EXPR_NEW column
-- , Place here the result got in the EXPR_COLNAME column
FROM MYTAB A, MYTAB B
, 
(
  SELECT COLNO AS I
  FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'SYSCAT' AND TABNAME = 'TABLES'
    AND TYPENAME NOT LIKE '%LOB'
) I
WHERE A.RN_ = 1 AND B.RN_ = 2
) 
WHERE INITIAL IS DISTINCT FROM NEW;
```

The result I got in my database:

```
|INITIAL                   |NEW                       |COLNAME        |
|--------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|
|2019-06-04-22.44.14.493001|2019-06-04-22.44.14.502001|ALTER_TIME     |
|26                        |15                        |COLCOUNT       |
|2019-06-04-22.44.14.493001|2019-06-04-22.44.14.502001|CREATE_TIME    |
|2019-06-04-22.44.14.493001|2019-06-04-22.44.14.502001|INVALIDATE_TIME|
|2019-06-04-22.44.14.493001|2019-06-04-22.44.14.502001|LAST_REGEN_TIME|
|ATTRIBUTES                |AUDITPOLICIES             |TABNAME        |
```