# how to collect data from two rows in db and return it as a single row for each specific value?

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

In my database I have a table USERS with the data such as:

```
CONTACT_OPTION  | CONTRACT_IDENTITY
------------------------------------------------
jim@test.com    |    10074
+1 754321356    |    10074
17 adams ave    |    10074
mike@test.com   |    10075
+1 325353223    |    10075
```

When I make a simple

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
```

it returns all the records, however I need to group them, so that all records related to the single CONTRACT_IDENTITY are in one row, so the result of such query would be:

```
CONTACT_OPTION  |  CONTACT_OPTION_2  |  CONTACT_OPTION_3  |  CONTRACT_IDENTITY
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
jim@test.com    |  +1 754321356      |  17 adams ave      |  10074
    
mike@test.com   |  +1 325353223      |  NULL              |  10075
```

Is there a way to do so? I tried to combine the queries somehow, but with no luck, can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: This is called a [tag:pivot], FYI.

Comment: Odd that your table does not hold contact priority therefore impossible to guarantee the columns the option will drop in to. Also 3 options maximim?

Comment: And, is this MySQL or DB2? Please [edit] your tags to remove one, or [edit] your post to explain that you need SQL that's portable between the two.

Comment: @P.Salmon I think 3 options would be best and I can treat them as maximum
@O.Jones I meant `db2`, good catch, I will modify the tags, thanks!

Comment: If the [linked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2) don't help you, please don't hesitate to ask another question.