# Convert multiple record to multiple columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset like the below:

```
ID  Type    Email
1   A   emily&gmail.com
1   B   adam&gmail.com
1   C   tim&gmail.com
2   A   jim&gmail.com
2   C   kenny&gmail.com
3   A   sam&gmail.com
3   B   asd123&gmail.com
3   C   emma&gmail.com
4   D   jkl&gmail.com
4   F   tester&gmail.com
4   G   form&gmail.com
5   B   another&gmail.com
5   C   idk&gmail.com
```

which I want to convert to this format using SQL in Cloud DB2 instance:

```
ID   A                 B
1    emily&gmail.com   adam&gmail.com
2    jim&gmail.com     NULL
3    sam&gmail.com     asd123&gmail.com
4    NULL              NULL
5    NULL              another&gmail.com
```

As the example shows, In my original table I have 3 columns where the Type can be A, B, C, D, E, F or G. I want to create a new dataset where I keep only the ID column, and each ID has to be unique here. From the previous Type column, the A and B will be columns in this dataset.
If an ID has a Type of A in the first dataset, the corresponding email address will go to the A column. Same for B. If there is no A or B record in the first dataset, the values should be NULL.

I tried the following code but probably I have issues with the syntax:

```
SELECT ID
       MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'A' THEN T.EMAIL ELSE NULL END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'B' THEN T.EMAIL ELSE NULL END) AS B
  
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE T
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY ID` at the end of your query and see what happens.

Comment: Which effect or advantage should this "ELSE NULL" have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is the default behavior. You can remove it to make the query shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an answer here, because the answer is coming from the comments. I just missed the `GROUP BY`, and I can shorten the query by deleting the `ELSE NULL` part:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'A' THEN T.EMAIL END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ROLE = 'B' THEN T.EMAIL ELSE NULL END) AS B
  
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE T
GROUP BY ID
```